# defining map<int, vector<int> > return type gives random values on every run

Tags: python, c++, c++11, swig, swig-template

After building and calling it using `python main.py` it gives me result like this:

> > [array([22209328,    21870,        0], dtype=int32), array([24088960,    21870,        1], dtype=int32)]

Why is it happening? I can't find out the bug in my code.
I get only the last element of each array correct. rest shows some random number which I assume to be address.

**Expected output:**

> > [array([1, 0, 0], dtype=int32), array([2, 1, 1], dtype=int32)]

**h_map.cpp**

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
map<int, vector<int> >hash_map()
{
    map<int, vector<int> >dist;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        dist[i] = {i+1,i,i}; // 1,0,0    2,1,1
        // 0 --> 1,2,3,
        // 1-> 2,3,4
    }
    return dist;
}
```

**h_map.h**

```cpp
#ifndef H_MAP_H
#define H_MAP_H
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
map<int, vector<int> >hash_map();

#endif
```

**h_map.i**

````cpp
%module h_map
#define SWIGPYTHON_BUILTIN
%{
  #include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT  /* To import_array() below */
  #include "h_map.h"
%}
%include "std_map.i"
%import "std_vector.i" 
%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
    import_array();
%}

namespace std {
    %template(IntVector) vector<int>;
}
namespace std {
 %template (mapiv) std::map<int,vector<int> >;
}

%typemap(out) std::map<int, std::vector<int> >
{
    for(auto it:$1)
    {
        int subLength = it.second.size();
        npy_intp dims[1] = {subLength };
        PyObject* temp = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, PyArray_INT, it.second.data());
        $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, temp);        
    }       
}
%include "h_map.h"```
````

**build.sh**

```
g++ -fPIC -c h_map.cpp

swig -python -c++ -o h_map_wrap.cpp h_map.i

g++ -fPIC -c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3) -I /home/kriti/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include  h_map_wrap.cpp

g++ -shared h_map.o h_map_wrap.o -o _h_map.so -lm
```

**main.py**

```
import numpy as np
from h_map import hash_map
a = hash_map()
print(a)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
map<int, vector<int> >dist;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    for (int j =0;j<3;j++)
        dist[i].push_back(i*j);
}
```

After doing this, still the problem is same.

Comment: *Disclaimer: I never used SWIG*. [This link](http://blog.enthought.com/python/numpy-arrays-with-pre-allocated-memory/#.XTcTyUd7mHs) seems to says that `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` does not allocate its own memory. However, `for(auto it:$1)` create a temporary object as an iterator. Thus, the python object will point to memory that will be released right after, and may then contain garbage. Try `for(auto const & it:$1)`.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé It doesn't work. Still the same problem.

Comment: Then, maybe it is safer to allocate its own memory and use `PyArray_SimpleNewFromDescr` to specify that the python object owns the memory.

Comment: Where is `it.first` in `%typemap(out) std::map<int, std::vector<int> >`? Keys are not stored in result.

Comment: @MarekR right now I am trying to convert vector into arrays. I was getting in tuple so I am doing it for only vector part. Then I will extend it for defining deictionary.

Comment: @MarekR right now I am only focused on converting vector elements to array.